# Resuming consumption of messages from a previously created durable subscription - RabbitMQ - SQMP 1.0 -

Tags: amqp

I have a issue which we are encountering in our RabitMQ instance where, we are publishing the default Topic and there are dynamic consumer are coming up.

now scenario is, if a consumer B is consuming message and for some reason, that goes down, and later come up, it does not Resuming consumption of messages from a previously created durable subscription.

we need to re-create binding around that. this is a big concern.

we are seeing this issue with only AMQP 1.0

Comment: Spring AMQP does not support AMQP 1.0, only 0.9.1 (RabbitMQ); what client are you using? Please show code and configuration.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell for your prompt response.  Unfortunately I had to use spring amqp tag but the client which is using c# code base is willing to join RabbitMQ but have a hard constrant of AMQP 1.0 and thats where we are seeing real challange. it was demonstrated to us where a dynamic consumer read from a topic and when we bring that down and resubscribe, it never binding and just loose the connection.

Comment: Please don't abuse tags in future; but I am sure whoever can answer this question will need much more information - code, configuration, versions, logs, etc, etc.